# VB.NET : Decompress a String, compressed from PHP via

Tags: php, vb.net, gzip, compression, gzipstream

I have a PHP Script which sends me information like this:

```
$output = base64_encode(gzencode('Hallo Welt',9));
```

I get this from a HTTP-Request into a string.

This is what I get into VB.NET:

`H4sIAAAAAAACC/NIzMnJVwhPzSkBAHUUKFAKAAAA`

Every try to decompress this with the help of `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` just doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the output in VB ?

Comment: Did you notice that the string is also base64 encoded? The PHP gzencode will probably return a byte array that is then transformed into a base64 string for sending. First transform the string back (`System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringyouget)`), then use the gzstream with the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

As I have wrote in my comment: The PHP code first compresses your text using GZip but then also converts the resulting bytes to a base64 string. Before you can decompress this you need to reverse the base64 process. This is how it works in VB:

```vb
'Convert base64 string to byte array
Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String("H4sIAAAAAAACC/NIzMnJVwhPzSkBAHUUKFAKAAAA")

'Standard GZipStream code for decompression
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    Using gzs As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
        Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader(gzs)
            Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadToEnd)
        End Using 'rdr
    End Using 'gzs
End Using 'ms
Console.ReadKey()
```

It produces your input string "Hallo Welt" again.

Converting a byte array to base64 when you send it over a text based system is a good idea, because you don't have problems with text encodings and unprintable characters. Base64 uses a printable subset of symbols to represent all values from 0-255, thus making it pretty perfect for sending.